# How do I display all the values of a multi dimentional array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Hey I have an array that contains an array:

```
$outPutResults = array();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
            {
                $outPutResults[] = $row['industry'];
                $outPutResults[] = $row['location'];
                $outPutResults[] = $row['title'];
                $outPutResults[] = $row['description'];
            }

        $searchResults[] = $outPutResults;
```

I am little confused how I would echo the contents.

As far as I am aware `$outputresults[]` should now be contained within `$searchresults[]`.

To output the content I'm using :

```
foreach ($searchResults[0] as $item) {echo $item;}
```

But this is only echoing the first set of results so rather than having to repeat the above and changing the number (0) each time how would i do it so it outputs all the sub arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You should nest two loops. For example like this:

```
foreach ($searchResults as $array) {
  foreach ($array as $item){
    echo $item;
  }
}
```

Comment: any change i can get a up vote as i can no longer post questions

Answer (score 0):

Just nest your foreach:

```
foreach ($searchResults as $row) {
    foreach($row as $item) {
       echo $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but could you perhaps explain how this works?

Answer (score 0):

```
$outPutResults = array();
$i = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
    $outPutResults[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
}

foreach ($outPutResults as $items) 
    foreach($items as $item)
        echo $item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing

```
$searchResults[] = $outPutResults;
```

instead of just

```
$searchResults = $outPutResults;
```

Then you don't have to worry about nesting your foreach statements.